# Ionic 2 rc0 whitescreen (No provider for ConnectionBackend!)

Tags: ionic2

I started a new ionic 2 rc0 app by copying the files of my old beta11 project. I did the necessary steps as described under

**Copying your Project to a New Project** : [ionic 2 rc0 changelog](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#steps-to-upgrade-to-rc0)

Now finally after getting no more compiler errors when I run

```
ionic run android -c
```

I'm just getting a **whitescreen** on my android phone.

Chrome debug is logging me

> Uncaught Error: No provider for t!

When I'm running

```
ionic serve -c
```

the **firefox** logs me

> Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for ConnectionBackend! ;
>   Zone: ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Object { ...

**app.module.ts** looks like:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage'; // special thing
import { Http } from '@angular/http';#

// other imports ....

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    // PAGES
    // MODALS
    // CUSTOM COMPONENTS
    // DIRECTIVES
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    // PAGES
    // MODALS
  ],
  providers: [
    Storage,
    Http,
    // SERVICES/PROVIDERS
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I'm guessing there is something wrong with a provider somewhere, but I just can't find a solution ...

System : **ubuntu 16.04 / node v6.7.0 / npm v3.10.3**

---

**EDIT :**

---

I started a new sidemenu project with

```
ionic start debugProject sidemenu --v2
```

I did this to to debug the providers by sequentially adding the providers of my original Project. It appears that, when I inject the first provider called **"Config"** in the constructor of **app.components.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from 'ionic-native';

import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

// PROVIDERS -> providers
import { Config } from '../providers/config/config';


@Component({
  template: `<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>`
})
export class MyApp {

  rootPage = TabsPage;

  constructor(
    platform  : Platform,
    config    : Config    <-------------(HERE !!! )
  ) { .....
```

I get the the Error message like before:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for ConnectionBackend! ;
>   Zone: ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Object { ...

**config.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

// providers
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
//import { DB } from '../db/db';


@Injectable()
export class Config {

  public data : any;

  constructor(
    public http : Http,
    //public db   : DB
  ){
    this.data = {};
  }

  loadDefault() {
    this.data = {
    ..........................
    // DATA OBJECT DEFINITIONS
    ...........................
    };
    return Promise.resolve("default settings applied");
  }

  loadSettingsFromDB(){
    return Promise.resolve("no local settings from db for now");
  }

  // TODO: send settings to server
  saveSettingsToDB(settings){
    return Promise.resolve("cant save settings for now");
  }

  handleError(err) : void {
    // error stacktrace gets returned on development mode
    try{
      err = err.json();
    }catch(e){}
    var msg = err.message || "LOADING ERROR";
    if(err.error){
      msg += err.error;
      //Toast.showLongBottom(msg).subscribe();
    }else{
      //Toast.showShortBottom(msg).subscribe();
    }
    console.log("ERROR in config.ts");
    console.log(msg);
    console.log(err);
  }

}
```

any ideas ? if not, any experience about opening a new issue on github ?

Comment: What is `ConnectionBackend`? I don't see it anywhere

Comment: me neither ... seems to be sth like a submodule of the providers. In a early version of angular 2 ConnectionBackend could be importet via '@angular/http' package, but I'm pretty sure this is a implicit error of ConnectionBackend

Comment: 1. there is no HTTP_PROVIDERS module under '@angular/http' and 2. there is a example project written in ionic 2 rc0 where they use Http like I did https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app/blob/master/src/providers/conference-data.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. It seems like I can't/shouldn't use the Http module in the providers array in **app.modules.ts** (In beta11 this was not a problem). My Config module relied on Http, so after constructing Config the application Error (No provider for ConnectionBackend) fired ...